# How do i get the option selected by a user using the Dropdown button to operate on?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, office-ui-fabric

I am new to react and office-ui-fabric and I am trying to create a VSCode Extension takes certain input parameters and based on the input the user selects, I should be operating on the option selected. I take the user input in the form of options under dropdown button. Currently once the user selects one of the options from the dropdown i do not see the option selected in the dropdown.I see only undefined being displayed in the console.

I have tried different ways of getting this input parameters from the user but i still end up with undefined being show in the console.

```
const Options: IDropdownOption[] = [
        { key: 'A', text: 'A', itemType: DropdownMenuItemType.Header },
        { key: 'B', text: 'B' },
        { key: 'C', text: 'C' },
        ];

const [selectedItem, setOption] = React.useState<string | undefined>(undefined);

return (
        <div>
      <Dropdown placeholder="Select option" options={Options} styles={dropdownStyles} selectedKey={selectedItem} onChange={event =>{
                              setOption((event.target as HTMLInputElement).value);console.log(selectedItem)}}  />   
 )
```

windows.console should show me the input the user selects whereas currently i see undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `office-ui-fabric` `Dropdown` component triggers change events via the [`onChanged`](https://unpkg.com/office-ui-fabric-react@0.22.1/index.html#/examples/dropdown) prop which when invoked, passes the actual option object underlying the drop down item that has been selected by the user.

By changing `onChange` to `onChanged`, and then revising this events handler to read the `text` of the selected option (rather than `value` of the `event.target`) that should produce the required result:

```
<Dropdown placeholder="Select option" 
          options={Options} 
          styles={dropdownStyles} 
          selectedKey={selectedItem} 
          onChanged={ selectedOption =>{
              setOption(selectedOption.text);
              console.log("Selected", selectedOption.text);
          }}/>
```

**Update**

This: `setOption(selectedOption.text);` calls the `setOption()` function, and passes the display value of the option selected by the user to it. When calling `setOption()`, this updates the stat `selectedItem` state of the component with the value that is passed (ie the display value of the selected option). Note that a side effect of calling `setOption()` is that a re-render of the component will occour, meaning that parts of your component displaying/relying on `selectedItem` will be automatically updated, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! changing onChange to onChanged and revising the events handler displays [object Object ] in the console log and not one of the option 'A' or 'B;' .

Comment: You're welcome :) - just updated answer. Does that help?

Comment: Thanks ! This worked. Can you help me understand what this line does selectedOption =>{
              setOption(selectedOption.text);?

Comment: @novice_coder you're welcome, just expanded the answer - hope that helps :)